# Initializing variable length array

Tags: c, variable-length-array, array-initialization

On initializing a Variable length array compiler gives an error message:

```
[Error] variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

Code snippet:

```
int n; 
printf("Enter size of magic square: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

int board[n][n] = {0};
```

How should **Variable Length arrays** be initialized?
And why it's all elements are not initialized to `0` in the way give below;

```
   int board[n][n];
   board[n][n] = {0};
```

?

Comment: If you are using cpp then use fill(&board[0][0], &board[n-1][n-1]+1, 0) to initialize all elements with 0 or any value you choose

Answer (score 22, accepted):

VLAs cannot be *initialized* by any form of initialization syntax. You have to *assign* the initial values to your array elements after the declaration in whichever way you prefer.

#### C11: 6.7.9 Initialization (p2 and p3):

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.
>
> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type **that is not a variable length array type**.

Comment: you mean to say
`int board[n][n];`
`board[n][n] = {0};`. right?

Comment: @haccks: No. Arrays are not assignable. This is why I said "assign the initial values to your array *elements*". Barring such raw-memory operations like `memset` or `memcpy`, it has to be done in element by element fashion. So, I meant to say `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) ...` and so on.

Comment: I read that array can be initialized as `array[m][n] = {0}`, this will initialize its first element to `0` and remaining elements get initialized to `0` itself.

Comment: @haccks: "Initialized" means that `= { 0 }` can be specified as an initializer in a declaration. What you have in your first comment is  completely incorrect. And even in a declaration it works with non-VLA arrays only. For example, you can do `int array[10][10] = { 0 }`. Yet this question is specifically about VLA arrays. VLA arrays do not accept initializers. You cannot do `int array[m][n] = { 0 }` when `m` and `n` are not constants.

Answer (score 28):

You'll have to use `memset`:

```
memset(board, 0, sizeof board);
```

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @haccks you just put that below your line `int board[n][n];`. And make sure you `#include <string.h>`

Comment: `#include <string.h>` for C.

Comment: You wanted to initialize it to `0`, right?

Comment: memset is clean you can also shift left the size of the array… In this case *board <<= n * n;

Answer (score 0):

1.You can simply initialize the array as follows-

```
int n; 
printf("Enter size of magic square: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

int board[n][n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
   {
      board[i][j] = 0;
   }
}
```

2. **memset()** should only be used when you want to set the array to "0".

Comment: "*... memset() should be usesd only when you want to set the array to "0".*" Hu! Why this?

Comment: @alk : The `memset()` function fills the first n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s with the constant byte c. Whereas, size of integer is generally 4 bytes so we cant set the integer to our desired number but "0" is a special case since with "0", `memset()` sets all bytes to "0".

Comment: @ParagGangil; *memset() should be usesd only when you want to set the array to "0"*: [Not true](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24207698/2455888).