# Initialised array to value 0 inside a block of code

Tags: c, default-value, array-initialization

Here's the snippet

```
main(){
//
  while(){
  int b;
  scanf("%d",&b);
  int arr[b];
  }
}
```

Ok now, Since I don't know the exact bound of array, I have to take in as a variable**using scanf**. And the array created contains garbage value. And for that purpose I have to initialize each element to 0, because that is what I want.

Is there a way I can get this thing to work, without having to initialize every time inside the loop?

Thanks

**EDIT** 
I guess I can use calloc to allocate the memory. Will there be a different in memory used?

Comment: @PHIfounder gcc accepts it without error.

Comment: The array size should be defined .

Comment: Compile with -Wall... like `gcc -Wall prog.c -pedantic -o prog` .

Comment: Of course you can use `calloc()`.

Comment: @meaning-matters Then instead of asking he should have tried it first ? what say?

Comment: What about using a macro for size?

Comment: @meaning-matters Yeah, I did try it before editing it, but will there be any difference in the memory usage in two cases?

Comment: @haccks Can't do that, I will have to run the same process multiple times, within the while loop, and each time I'll have different boundary index. and also the index is user input. Is there a way of incorporating this using macro?

Comment: If you use `calloc`, it will exist on the heap, while what you have will exist on the stack. The stack has limited memory, so if `b` is several million, you are going to have problems.

Comment: @Kraken; Is your compiler supports C99 features?

Comment: @MarkLakata how does the memory allocation differ in two ways, when the value of `b` is not yet taken from the user? Is the memory allocated at run time?

Comment: `memset(arr,0,sizeof(int)*b)`

Comment: How about `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));`?

Comment: @haccks I am using gcc.

Comment: Yes, the memory is allocated (from the stack) at run-time, but this is true even if `b` was a constant.

Comment: Then it supports c99. You can use VLA(variable length array). Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332360/initializing-variable-length-array) will help you.

Comment: @Kraken You can do it like this `scanf("%d",b); arr[b];`.As if you just want to decide the size of array at run time. Look you got your answer below :)

Comment: @MarkLakata If b was constant and I used `int arr[5]` then the memory would have been run time or compile time? Then why do we call malloc allocation dynamic if both are the same and occur at runtime?

Comment: It depends on the compiler. Most compilers running on a normal operating system (Linux, Windows, etc) will take memory from the stack at run-time for local variables, also known as `auto` variables. The amount that they take is either known (`int arr[5]`) or unknown (`int arr[b]`).  But the memory left in the stack is generally unknown to the application, so there is no guarantee that there will be enough memory on the stack at run-time. Some embedded compilers do NOT use a stack. In that case, all allocation happens at compile time, and `int arr[b]` is not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an array of run-time size, then the proper approach depends on how large your array is going to be.

If the value of `b` can be large, then declaring it as a local array can lead to stack overflow. In that case the better idea would be to dynamically allocate your array using `calloc`. `calloc` will properly zero-initialize an `int` array.

If the array is relatively small and safe to allocate on the stack, the you can simply declare it as a local array (which is what you did in your original code) and then set it to all-zeros by using `memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr)`.

Of course, in both cases you might end up with a hidden memory-zeroing cycle implemented inside the library function. In general case it is not possible to set a large region of memory to zero without using a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports C99 then you can easily use VLA's;

```
int a, b; 
printf("Enter size of array: ");
scanf("%d",&b);

int arr[b];
```

and to initialize its all elements to zero in your case use an inner loop or standard library function `memset`.

```
memset(b, 0, sizeof(b));
```

Comment: @PHIfounder Yeah, but your comment is just after mine :)

Comment: @AndreyT; I think no!

Comment: OOOOps  I didn't see it , +1 nevertheless, AndreyT answer is recommendable :)

Comment: Actually, That is what I am already doing. Sorry If it was not clear.

Comment: @Kraken But that ain't visible in your code , So what is the problem . It should work though.

Comment: @Kraken; But you have written *Since I don't know the exact bound of array* in your question........I am surprised!

Comment: @Kraken; Still it is not clear. If you have used VLA, then it must not take garbage value after initialization.

Comment: @Kraken; still my technique will work if you will use an inner loop for initialization.