# How memset initializes an array of integers by -1?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, twos-complement, memset

The [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) says about `memset`:

> ```
> #include <string.h>
> void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)
> ```
>
> The `memset()` function fills the first `n` **bytes** of the memory area pointed to by `s` with the constant byte `c`.

It is obvious that `memset` can't be used to initialize `int` array as shown below:

```
int a[10];
memset(a, 1, sizeof(a));
```

it is because `int` is represented by 4 bytes (say) and one can not get the desired value for the integers in array `a`.
But I often see the programmers use  `memset` to set the `int` array elements to either `0` or `-1`.

```
int a[10];
int b[10];
memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));  
memset(b, -1, sizeof(b));
```

As per my understanding, initializing with integer `0` is OK because `0` can be represented in 1 byte (may be I am wrong in this context). But how is it possible to initialize `b` with `-1` (a 4 bytes value)?

Comment: You are slightly wrong about the reason initializing with `0` is OK.  It is OK because `0` fits in an `unsigned char` (so it is not truncated when used as the second argument to `memset`) *and* because the bit pattern in memory for a `sizeof(int)`-byte zero is identical to the bit pattern in memory for `sizeof(int)` sequential one-byte zeros.  Both of those things must be true for this to work.  In fact, those things are true for exactly two numbers in twos-complement arithmetic: `0` and `-1`.

Comment: @zwol: Hmm? The first sentence speaks of zeros and so is not literally true for −1. So presumably you intend to implicitly parameterize the first sentence: It works for *x* if the bits for an `int` with value *x* are the same as the bits for `sizeof(int)` `unsigned char` each with the value *x*. Further, we must consider the `unsigned char` with value *x* as resulting from conversion of *x* to `unsigned char`, as −1 is not representable. If so, then it is not true that 0 and −1 are the only such values. 16,843,009 • *x* works for any integer 0 ≤ *x* < 256. (16,843,009 is hex 1010101).

Comment: @zwol: Except for the fact that C does not require the bit positions in integers of different widths to represent the same values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't understand your example.  No multiple of 16,843,009 is representable by any of the `char` types (well, unless you're on a machine where `CHAR_BIT >= 25`.)

Comment: @zwol: `0x34343434` is a multiple of 16,843,009; it is `0x34 * 0x01010101`. `int a; memset(&a, 0x34343434, sizeof a);` will set each byte of `a` to `0x34`. Then the value of `a` will be `0x34343434`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, you're relying on internal truncation of the second argument to `memset`.  I consider that to be cheating because `memset` would take an `unsigned char` second argument if not for back-compat with traditional C.

Comment: @zwol: But you did that with −1. `memset` takes an `int`, converts it to an `unsigned char`, and copies it into each byte. −1 is not representable as an `unsigned char`; it gets converted to `UCHAR_MAX`. So, if you are allowing that, then `0x34343434` (or a similar value in case of larger-byte C implementations) works the same way.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Converting `(int)-1` to `signed char` does not change its value; converting 0x34343434 to any form of `char` does change its value (when `CHAR_BIT` has its usual value).  I'm not sure why you're banging on unsigned vs. signed; the question was clearly about signed quantities.

Comment: @zwol: `memset` is defined in terms of `unsigned char`. There is no `signed char` or `char` in either the posted question or in the C specification of `memset`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Oddly, the reason this works with `-1` is exactly the same as the reason that this works with zeros: in [two's complement binary representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), `-1` has `1`s in all its bits, regardless of the size of the integer, so filling in a region with bytes filled with all `1`s produces a region of `-1` signed `int`s, `long`s, and `short`s on two's complement hardware.

On hardware that differs from two's complement the result will be different. The `-1` integer constant would be converted to an `unsigned char` of all ones, because the standard is specific on how the conversion has to be performed. However, a region of bytes with all their bits set to `1` would be interpreted as integral values in accordance with the rules of the platform. For example, on sign-and-magnitude hardware all elements of your array would contain the smallest negative value of the corresponding type.

Comment: Wouldn't using `~0` be effectively the same (and more clear)?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Yes, using `~0` would definitely avoid the confusion here.

Comment: I got your answer but could you explain this line: *so filling in a region with -1 bytes produces a region of -1 signed ints, longs, and shorts.*?

Comment: Just have a look a the binary representation of an integer carring  `-1`. @haccks

Comment: @haccks If you fill with all-ones bit pattern a region of memory that corresponds to a `sizeof` of some integral type (`int`, `long`, or `short`) and then re-interpret that region as the corresponding integral type, you would see `-1` on computers with two-s complement representation. Note that on rare occasions when you have a sign-magnitude hardware you would see the smallest negative integer representable on that hardware (I have never seen such hardware, or even a person who mentioned seeing such hardware, but I heard that it does exist).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight; Yes. Actually this confuses me: *filling in a region with `-1`*. I thought it there would be `1` intead of `-1`.

Comment: @haccks You are right, using `-1` as a "shortcut" for a "byte filled with all ones" is platform-specific. I added some clarifications to this, along with the long comment above. Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Which is more confusing depends on the background of the reader. I once confused a colleague by using `~0`, and in the following discussion it became clear that `-1` would not have been confusing to that colleague. I think there are quite a few C/C++ programmers who don't even know that there is something like the `~` operator.

Comment: "On hardware that differs from two's complement... -1 integer constant would be converted to an unsigned char of all ones".  Say on a 32-bit sign-magnitude machine, would not `-1` --> `0x80000001` and then truncate to 8-bits as `0x01` into each byte resulting in `0x01010101`?  I'd expect `~0` to covert to "all ones", but not necessarily `-1`.

Comment: @chux The standard says that in order to convert a negative integral value to `unsigned` the compiler must subtract the magnitude of the negative value from the 2^N, where N is the number of bits in the unsigned integral type. Here, N is 8, so the result is 256-1=255, an unsigned value. This is how they avoided making the process implementation-defined without requiring 2s complement representation. That's why my understanding is that `-1` would be converted to an all-ones bit pattern regardless of the way the negatives are represented on the target platform.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I see.  Although I think the conversion is `-1` to `size_t` (where bit-width may be 32) and then `memset()` uses `(unsigned char)` bits of `size_t n`.  Either way, comes up with all ones.  Need to remember all this should one encounter such a machine. ;-)

Comment: +1 for the comment that the standard actually specifies signed-unsigned conversion. I always thought that was platform specific.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Another storage method is BCD, such as is found on anything which is based on the [IBM 360 architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360_architecture), in which -1 would be represented in 1 byte as `x'1D'`, in 2 bytes as `x'00 1D'`, and with further leading zeroes as required after that. I'm struggling to see how C could validly be implemented with that as the default type for `int`, but I think it serves to illustrate an actual instance of a non-twos-complement architecture.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Couldn’t `~0` theoretically produce a trap representation, and thus not be equivalent to `-1`?

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realized `memset` on non-2's-complement machines would have to actually do int->unsigned conversion (because it's not a no-op there).  I guess it dates back to such early C history (probably before prototypes) that it couldn't have been declared to take `unsigned` or `unsigned char`, but it's weird that in the asm the caller doesn't necessarily pass the bit-pattern it wants.

Answer (score 8):

## When all bits of a number are **`0`**, its value is also **0**. However, if all bits are **`1`** the value is **-1**.

If we write `int a[2]`, ***4x2*** bytes of memory is allocated which contains random/garbage bits-

```
00110000 00100101 11100011 11110010    11110101 10001001 00111000 00010001
```

Then, we write `memset(a, 0, sizeof(a))`. Now, `memset()` works byte by byte, and one byte representation (`unsigned char`) of **0** is `00000000`. So, it becomes-

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Therefore, both `a[0]` and `a[1]` are initialized with **0**.

---

Now, lets see `memset(a, -1, sizeof(a))`: one byte for **-1** is `11111111`. And, we get-

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111    11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Here, both `a[0]` and `a[1]` will have the value **-1**.

---

However, for `memset(a, 1, sizeof(a))`: **1** in a byte is `00000001`-

```
00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001    00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001
```

So, the value will be- **16843009**.

Comment: `void *memset( void *dest, int ch, size_t count );` => Copies the value `ch` (after conversion to `unsigned char`) into each of the first count characters of the object pointed to by `dest`.